# Mysql interupt query and start from latest ID another query

Tags: php, mysql

I got a set of queries that will be interupted. Therefore I need to stop the query, save the last added ID and continue adding contents from the last ID on another day.

Szenario:

1) I query data from another table (Table-A) like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_A
ORDER BY uID ASC
```

2) Then I add to a table (Table-B) that "looks" like this:

```
|¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯|
| uID | SubID* | Name | Foo | Bar |
|-----|--------|------|-----|-----|
|  1  |   23   | Boo  | Goo | Shu |
|_____|________|______|_____|_____|
```

3) For each row I query from the Table-A table I add data to the Table-B table. (*Note: This table already has the uID, SubID and Name when I add the data.*)

4) The query gets interrupted/stops. Then I save the uID* of the latest added row - before the queries stop - to a separate table (Table-C).

**Question:** How can I start the query - after interruption *(let's say on the next day)* - again, but starting from the next row after last I saved on the previous day (The uID will be available).

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $table_A
ORDER BY uID ASC
LIMIT $last_uID, COUNT $table_A (a.k.a "the last ID in the table")
```

Thanks!

*Notes:*

- *The SubID connect rows to other tables & can exist more than once.*
- *UID = Unique Identifier (Auto Increment).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you know what the last ID added was, because it will be in table_B.

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_A
WHERE uID > (select max(uID) from table_B)
ORDER BY uID ASC
```

UPDATE:

Seems this is what is required.

```
SELECT all columns
FROM $table_A
WHERE uID BETWEEN $last_uID_added AND $last_uID_in_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for your A. I know what the uID is (as written in the Q). I just forgot to state that some of the data is already present - like the uID - sorry for that. My Question is: How can I say (in MySQL) "SELECT all columns FROM $table_A WHERE uID = $last_uID_added UNTIL $last_uID_in_table"? I guess the `max` won't work in this case, because there are already all the uIDs present.

Comment: SELECT all columns FROM $table_A WHERE uID BETWEEN $last_uID_added AND $last_uID_in_table;

Comment: Could you update your A? That was exactly was I was searching.